# How do I make Soap calls using PHP SoapClient to salesforce without the Salesforce PHP Toolkit?

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

```
$client = new SoapClient('enterprise.wsdl');
print_r($client->login(SFDC_LOGIN, SFDC_PASSWORD.SFDC_API_TOKEN));
$client->__setLocation(TOKEN_URL);
```

I receive an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION] UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService in /Library/WebServer/Documents/custom/index.php:18

In this case this doesn't provide much useful information, it does tell me that I either need to set a destination URL or catch the returned URL?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Note:

I don't want to use the Salesforce PHP toolkit because I don't want to add anything extra to my company web server, if I don't have to.

Comment: This URL might give you a hint in the right direction: http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2012/04/13/salesforce-and-soapui-using-the-default-query-method/  . That said, the phpforce toolkit can be helpful (though I've found it needs tweaks) and might be worth the headache of writing your own.

Comment: I think that blog puts me on the right track! Thank you so much for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some digging from aynber's idea.  I came up with this...

I downloaded SoapUI-5.2.1 for my mac from https://www.soapui.org.

From there I combined that program with the Enterprise WSDL file from salesforce.  Using the program to "pre build" the soap call for me.  I then pulled out the pieces that I needed and used cURL to submit the soap envelope.

This allowed me to convert the leads using previously created Account IDs/Contact IDs. After converting the Lead, I am now able to go back and modify the opportunity ID which I also created pre lead conversion.

Here is the code I came up with...

```
$soapSubmission='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"><soapenv:Header><urn:SessionHeader><urn:sessionId>'.$creds[0].'</urn:sessionId></urn:SessionHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><urn:convertLead>';
        foreach($postInfo as $orderKey=>$values){
            $additionString='<urn:leadConverts>';
            if(isset($values['SFDC_IDs']['Account'])){
                $additionString.='<urn:accountId>'.$values['SFDC_IDs']['Account'].'</urn:accountId>';
            }
            if(isset($values['SFDC_IDs']['Contact'])){
                $additionString.='<urn:contactId>'.$values['SFDC_IDs']['Contact'].'</urn:contactId>';
            }
            $additionString.='<urn:convertedStatus>Converted</urn:convertedStatus>';
            $additionString.='<urn:doNotCreateOpportunity>true</urn:doNotCreateOpportunity>';
            $additionString.='<urn:leadId>'.$values['SFDC_IDs']['Lead'].'</urn:leadId>';
            $additionString.='<urn:overwriteLeadSource>false</urn:overwriteLeadSource>';
            $additionString.='<urn:ownerId>'.self::IT_SERVICE_ID.'</urn:ownerId>';
            $additionString.='<urn:sendNotificationEmail>false</urn:sendNotificationEmail>';
            $additionString.='</urn:leadConverts>';

            $soapSubmission.=$additionString;
        }
        $soapSubmission.='</urn:convertLead></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

        $ch=curl_init($creds[1]);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$soapSubmission);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
            "SOAPAction: convertLead"
          ));
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
```

Comment: Can't you use javascript? there is a javascript library called https://jsforce.github.io/start/, take a look.

Comment: I'm sure I could have. I was using PHP because the backend of the system that is feeding this code data was also written in PHP.